# Unity Player stuck in air cannot move even with move tool

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have making a game similar to Mario for my understanding . I came across to a problem when i was giving the final touches to my game i ran it last time i saw that my player is not able to move like it show moving animation , jump animation and can even shoot bullets , I even tried it moving with move tool while playing the game . The background was following the player as programed ( it is following the mouse as i try to move the player from move tool ) after removing and checking the rigid body , box collider . Even after that it is not reacting with gravity . There was a error code i was receiving before , after restarting the unity it was gone the code is

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: _unity_self
UnityEditor.SerializedObject.FindProperty (System.String propertyPath) (at <35c0e5f206594d2fa707969117964d70>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindPropertyRelative (UnityEngine.UIElements.IBindable field, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <a26505b064194c429b83f4a02cfddb4d>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.BindTree (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <a26505b064194c429b83f4a02cfddb4d>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectBindingContext.ContinueBinding (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element, UnityEditor.SerializedProperty parentProperty) (at <a26505b064194c429b83f4a02cfddb4d>:0)
UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.DefaultSerializedObjectBindingImplementation+BindingRequest.Bind (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement element) (at <a26505b064194c429b83f4a02cfddb4d>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeBindingsUpdater.Update () (at <b8c852c145a8456ba2512bf23f96ab0b>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdater.UpdateVisualTreePhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualTreeUpdatePhase phase) (at <b8c852c145a8456ba2512bf23f96ab0b>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.Panel.UpdateBindings () (at <b8c852c145a8456ba2512bf23f96ab0b>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.UpdateSchedulers () (at <b8c852c145a8456ba2512bf23f96ab0b>:0)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.UpdateSchedulers () (at <b8c852c145a8456ba2512bf23f96ab0b>:0)
UnityEditor.RetainedMode.UpdateSchedulers () (at <a26505b064194c429b83f4a02cfddb4d>:0)
```

and this is my code for moving the player

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 5f;

    private Rigidbody2D myBody;
    private Animator anim;

    public Transform groundCheckPosition;
    public LayerMask groundLayer;

    private bool isGrounded;
    private bool jumped;

    private float jumpPower = 12f;

    void Awake()
    {
        myBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        CheckIfGrounded();
        PlayerJump();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        PlayerWalk();
    }

    void PlayerWalk()
    {

        float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        if (h > 0)
        {
            myBody.velocity = new Vector2(speed, myBody.velocity.y);

            ChangeDirection(1);

        }
        else if (h < 0)
        {
            myBody.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, myBody.velocity.y);

            ChangeDirection(-1);

        }
        else
        {
            myBody.velocity = new Vector2(0f, myBody.velocity.y);
        }

        anim.SetInteger("speed", Mathf.Abs((int)myBody.velocity.x));

    }

    void ChangeDirection(int direction)
    {
        Vector3 tempScale = transform.localScale;
        tempScale.x = direction;
        transform.localScale = tempScale;
    }

    void CheckIfGrounded()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics2D.Raycast(groundCheckPosition.position, Vector2.down, 0.1f, groundLayer);

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            // and we jumped before
            if (jumped)
            {

                jumped = false;

                anim.SetBool("Jump", false);
            }
        }

    }

    void PlayerJump()
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                jumped = true;
                myBody.velocity = new Vector2(myBody.velocity.x, jumpPower);

                anim.SetBool("Jump", true);
            }
        }
    }

} // class
```

I tried to changed the all the property of the player even it is not reacting with gravity
here is a link to understand better
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NwAPjniLtGENJqH8PjNRvVMnO7bsfwVB?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that your public variables are all properly assigned in the editor?

```
public Transform groundCheckPosition;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
```

Comment: Problem is solved it is related to animator . My friend removed all the components one by one and checked it and it worked